# Functor of points of $X_{red}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $X_{red}$ be its reduction (defined through its universal property). What is the functor of points of $X_{red}$? Put differently, which maps $\phi : \text{Spec }R \to X$ factor through the reduction of $X$?

I am reading notes by Marc-Nieper Wißkirchen which claim that $\phi^{-1}X_{red} = \text{Spec }R/\sqrt{0}$, but this can not be true, as witnessed by the morphism $\text{Spec }\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)\to \text{Spec }\mathbb C[x]$. The reduction of the line $\mathbb A_\mathbb C$ is all of it, so the pullback must be all of the thickened point.

Comment: I believe a morphism of schemes $\pi: Y \to X$ factors through the reduction iff each $\mathcal O_Y(U) \to \mathcal O_X(\pi^{-1}U)$ kills nilpotents. This gives me one description, if I am correct?

Comment: The arrow in the ring map looks incorrect (or maybe it’s $X \rightarrow Y$, or $O_X(U) \rightarrow O_Y(\pi^{-1}(U))$)?

Comment: @Aphelli Yes, it should be $\mathcal O_X(U)\to \mathcal O_Y(\pi^{-1}U)$.

Comment: Then I think your criterion is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is, since any morphism of schemes $Y\to X$ factorizes uniquely through $X_{red}$ if $Y$ is a reduce scheme.

Comment: That is cool, but I actually hoped for a simpler criterion. For example if M.N. Wißkirchen were correct, then $\phi: \text{Spec }A\to X$ would factor iff $A$ would be reduced, but this is clearly false.

Comment: Yes it is: the "only if" part is false!